# How the degree of standard representation of $S_n$ equals $n-1$?

Tags: representation-theory

I found this explanation of standard representation of $S_4$. How can I extend this notion and prove it for a vector space of $n$ dimension.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz15S.png)
Can someone also please explain how do I calculate character for this representation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Replace "four" by $n$, "three" by $n-1$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

An answer from a non-mathematician here....

The standard representation of $S_n$ deals with the permutation of $n$ objects.  Any individual permutation can be represented as an $n\times n$ matrix showing the $j$-th final location of the $i$-th element.  You might think that you need all of that information to specify a permutation.

**Except**  that if you know where the first $n-1$ objects end up, you automatically know where the last one ends up.   So you don't need an $n\times n$ matrix, you only need an $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrix.

Concretely, you can think of there being $n$ orthonormal vectors $\hat e_i$ matching the $n$ objects.  One way that I have seen the "standard representation"  determined is calculating the matrix that determines how $(\hat e_{i-1}- \hat e_i)$ changes under the permutation.